# NOT LIKE clause is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM client_info
WHERE (cid LIKE 'G%' OR cid LIKE 'H%' OR cid LIKE 'J%')
AND (client_name NOT LIKE 'P4%' OR client_name NOT LIKE 'P5%')
```

The results still contain client names starting with P4 and P5. What is wrong with NOT LIKE clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the second set's `OR` to an `AND`.

```
AND (client_name NOT LIKE 'P4%' AND client_name NOT LIKE 'P5%')
```

Comment: You're right about the `client_name` bit but using `AND` for the `cid` part of the `WHERE` clause would never return any records.

Comment: It worked there were quite a number of records with a space before P4 and P5. I just added % before P4 & P5, it working just fine. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @JimStewart `cid LIKE 'G%' AND cid LIKE 'H%'` is different with `cid = 'G' AND cid = 'H'` and the second one does not return any row.

Comment: @MikeCraford I would not recommend that. Use `LTRIM` to strip any  leading space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given you the correct answer - you need to use AND instead of OR.  But it's worth understanding why.  Take a client named P5_JONES, for instance - why is this patient showing up in the list?  Because its name is NOT LIKE 'P4%'.  Yes, it is like P5%, but with an OR in there, only one of those expressions needs to be true to satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use AND instead of OR in NOT LIKE condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM client_info
WHERE (cid LIKE 'G%' OR cid LIKE 'H%' OR cid LIKE 'J%')
AND (client_name NOT LIKE 'P4%' AND client_name NOT LIKE 'P5%')
```

You must use AND and not OR operator. Because you use NOT LIKE so, you must check either condition.